# MySQL Query help - Grouping and count problems

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL database that I am trying to get a specific count of data with a catch. The best way to explain this is by showing you.

I have a table that has a username and ID_no, that ID is not always going to be unique there are circumstances that will show a duplication of this (which is expected), the table might look like this

```
Username    ID_No
 User1  1111111
 User1  1111111
 User1  1111111
 User1  1111111
 User1  2222222
 User1  3333333
 User1  3333333
 User1  444444
 User1  444444
 User1  444444
 User1  555555
 User1  666666
```

I need to get a unique count of this which is a piece of cake

```
   Select username, count(Distinct id_no) 
   from Cases
   group by username
```

that gives me a count of 6. This is where it gets interesting I need to now join another table which will add a category so the table might look like this

```
Username    Cat ID_No
User1   Category1   1111111
User1   Category2   1111111
User1   Category2   1111111
User1   Category2   1111111
User1   Category5   2222222
User1   Category6   3333333
User1   Category7   3333333
User1   Category8   444444
User1   Category8   444444
User1   Category8   444444
User1   Category11  555555
User1   Category12  666666
```

With this I need to also get a unquie count, but the catch here is that I need to match the same number as before (6), but this is where I get stuck as to how I can do this in MySQL because as you can see there is categories that overlap so my query as simple as it is looks like this

```
   Select username, cat, count(Distinct id_no) 
   from Cases c
   join Case_details cd on c.id_no=cd.id_no
   group by username, cat
```

Because I am having to group by cat I get a count of 8. 
If this was SQL server I could do an inner query using a top 1 on the ID (I think), but mySQL will not let me use limit within a subquery.

So to be clear What I really need it to do look something like this

```
Username    Cat ID_No
User1   Category1   1111111

User1   Category5   2222222
User1   Category6   3333333

User1   Category8   444444

User1   Category11  555555
User1   Category12  666666
```

You will notice that only the first category that had the ID is shown. As a total count it would be 6 the same as the first, this is what I am looking for.

anyone got any ideas here?

Comment: You should join on both `username` and `id_no`.

Comment: You can use this: Select c.username, min(cd.cat), count(Distinct c.id_no) 
   from table1 c
   join table2 cd on c.id_no=cd.id_no
   group by c.username

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Tell us what exact result you need, sometimes instead of writing essay better give expecting result is good.

Comment: exact result I need is to be the same as the first query. So basiclly I need it to show me the categories but IF there is an ID on 2 or more categories then it should not add a count to these cats only the first one.

Comment: G one the Min will not work it shows only the one category, I will need to display all see revised at the top